# Is this a participial construction?

Tags: participles

> Ron's eyes strayed to the pile of Chocolate Frogs **waiting to be
>   unwrapped**.
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is the highlighted part a participial construction? – its semantic subject is Ron’s eyes;  the subject of to-infinitive is Chocolate Frogs and omitted because we know that.
Or is it just modifying the previous noun – Chocolate Frogs? Or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it is a participial construction.

The subject of the sentence is *Ron's eyes*; but the subject of the verbal *waiting* is either *pile* or *Chocolate Frogs*. I'd vote here for *Chocolate Frogs*, since a *pile* of confections is unlikely to be wrapped.

So this sentence employs a participial construction to combine two propositions:

- Ron's eyes strayed to the pile of Chocolate Frogs.
- The Chocolate Frogs were waiting to be unwrapped.

(Actually, the real sense of the second proposition is probably something more like *The Chocolate Frogs appeared to Ron's greedy eyes to be waiting to be unwrapped* - but that is a Literary Critical inference.)